# Increase touch sensitivity of iPhone app programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, touch

I am using too many number of images for buttons in my project. I found some issues while doing device test. App couldn't detecting the finger tapping sometimes. I need to increase the touch sensitivity programmatically to resolve this issue.

Comment: are you using UIImageView on top of UIButton? or setting background image of button?

Comment: setting background image of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like apple documentation says:

> Make it easy for people to interact with content and controls by giving each interactive element ample spacing. Give tappable controls a hit target of about 44 x 44 points.

Make the button tappable size at least 44x44 pixels and it should work.
More informations here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LayoutandAppearance.html

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible, but you might have smaller action button which you could resize little more or you can have bigger transparent action button behind your smaller action button so you can get what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Add images to button like this -

[image]

here you can see the button border are larger that image size, so you can increase the touch area of button in this way.
For further image adjustment inside button, you can use image insets, which are also present in the same inspector in xib.